# In google maps, how do i prevent the native infoWindow from showing up, in other words, how do i make it blank?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have my own version of html infoWindow and would like the native one to be blank so I can just display my own infoWindow, any idea how i could do this?[image: Googles infoWindow is also displaying]

My infoWindow exists as html and i just pull it in as a Node and pass it to the marker currently.

Comment: Is this for the Google Maps API? You didn't tag it that way so not sure

Comment: Sorry about that, it is now tagged as google-maps-api, thanks.

Comment: Think we need to see some code, particularly for 'i just pull it in as a Node and pass it to the marker'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming it's OK if there's no blank info window behind yours.

Adding a Marker doesn't cause an infowindow to be created, you have to add one through the click event on the marker. An example is here:
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-simple.html

The usual way to add a marker is to add it through the listener:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
  infowindow.open(map,marker);
});
```

However, it seems like what you want instead is this:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
  mycustominfowindow.open(map,marker);
});
```

Comment: What is mycustominfowindow in your case?

Comment: Sorry, I assumed you meant that you had a custom infowindow function. Are you asking how to create such a thing?